# Excel VBA - IF/AND Issue - If values from two columns match on separate sheets, copy a value from one sheet to another in another column

Tags: vba, excel

I want sheets "Status" and "Ref" compared. If the values match in both columns Status!F and Ref!B *AND* Status!Q and Ref!C for a particular individual's data in a row, then copy the value from Ref!F to Status!H

This is my first ever attempt at writing code so it's probably full of errors, but the debugger points out the first If statement in particular. I've tried it with and without parentheses.

```
Sub help()

    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim index As Integer


    Sheet1LastRow = Worksheets("Status").Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Sheet2LastRow = Worksheets("Ref").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row


    For index = 1 To Sheet1LastRow
        If ((Worksheets("Status").Cells(i, 6).Value = Worksheets("Ref").Cells(j, 2).Value) And (Worksheets("Status").Cells(i, 17).Value = Worksheets("Ref").Cells(j, 3).Value)) Then Worksheets("Status").Cells(i, 8).Value = Worksheets("Ref").Cells(j, 6)
    Next
    index = index + 1
    j = j + 1
    i = i + 1
    Do Until index = Sheet1LastRow
    Loop
End Sub
```

edit - a note--these sheets are not in the same order. so row 1500 in Status could match something on row 3 on ref, for example

Comment: When working with loops it's so important that you indent your code properly. I did it for you -- [with some help from Rubberduck](http://rubberduckvba.com/indentation).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
For i = 1 To Sheet1LastRow
    For j = 1 To Sheet2LastRow
        If ((Worksheets("Status").Cells(i, 6).Value = Worksheets("Ref").Cells(j, 2).Value) and (Worksheets("Status").Cells(i, 17).Value = Worksheets("Ref").Cells(j, 3).Value)) Then
            Worksheets("Status").Cells(i, 8).Value = Worksheets("Ref").Cells(j, 6).Value
            Exit for
        End if
    Next j
Next i
```

Comment: ACTUALLY I think it's working!! I set the variables to 1 because I realized it was looking for cell F0 which doesn't exist... THANK YOU!